# PySpark error: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o469.count

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a python spark program which behaves somewhere inconsistently and in some cases errors.
I usually run in on a small EMR cluster of two `c3.2xlarge` with a `m1.large` master and it runs fine and competes successfully.
However, when I run the exact same program on a larger cluster - I tried 4 `c3.2xlarge` with a `m1.large` master, it ends with an error.  I'll paste the error(s) below, but even these errors aren't quite consistent, not the error trace itself and not the stage at which it happens.
In one case for example, it happens after about 26min and on a `.count()` call and in and in another instance it actually passes the `.count()` successfully, but an error happens after about an hour and in a different stage, on a call to `.write.jdbc()`.
So I assume this is a kind of race condition but I'm not even sure whether it's my fault for improper usage of spark, or is this a bug in spark.
Most of the features I use in this case are from spark.sql.

Environment: Spark 1.5.2 on EMR (Elastic Mapreduce on AWS)

The stack traces are very long, so I can't paste the entire traces here, but hopefully just enough to get the context.
The code itself - well, there's a lot of it and I hadn't managed to find a simple repro test case that I can easily post here... (race conditions, you know...)

As noted, that's just part of the stack trace, it gets pretty long (example one):
Note that the error in both cases happens in different locations of the code.

**Any help or directions how to approach this problem?**

cheers

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.134231/spark_normalize_data.py", line 102, in <module>
    run_spark(args)
  File "/home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.134231/spark_normalize_data.py", line 62, in run_spark
    company_aliases_broadcast, experiences, args)
  File "/home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.134231/companies.py", line 50, in get_companies
    out(sc, args, 'companies', sql_create_table, companies)
  File "/home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.134231/output.py", line 48, in out
    mode='append')
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 455, in jdbc
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 36, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o464.jdbc.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(ref_company_size_id#96)
 TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,churn_rate#200,churn_rate_percentile#202,retention_rate_2y#210]
  SortMergeOuterJoin [id#85], [company_id#180], LeftOuter, None
   TungstenSort [id#85 ASC], false, 0
    TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#85)
     TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,churn_rate#200,(_we0#203 * 100.0) AS churn_rate_percentile#202]
      Window [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,churn_rate#200], [HiveWindowFunction#org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFPercentRank(churn_rate#200) WindowSpecDefinition ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING AS _we0#203], [ref_company_size_id#96], [churn_rate#200 ASC]
       TungstenSort [ref_company_size_id#96 ASC,churn_rate#200 ASC], false, 0
        TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(ref_company_size_id#96)
         TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,(100.0 * cast(pythonUDF#201 as double)) AS churn_rate#200]
          !BatchPythonEvaluation PythonUDF#divide(count#199L,emp_count#94L), [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,count#199L,pythonUDF#201]
           ConvertToSafe
            TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,count#199L]
             SortMergeOuterJoin [id#85], [company_id#180], LeftOuter, None
              TungstenSort [id#85 ASC], false, 0
               TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#85)
                TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,(_we0#198 * 100.0) AS avg_tenure_percentile#197]
                 Window [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196], [HiveWindowFunction#org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFPercentRank(avg_tenure#196) WindowSpecDefinition ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING AS _we0#198], [ref_company_size_id#96], [avg_tenure#196 ASC]
                  TungstenSort [ref_company_size_id#96 ASC,avg_tenure#196 ASC], false, 0
                   TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(ref_company_size_id#96)
                    TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg(duration_days)#195 AS avg_tenure#196]
                     SortMergeOuterJoin [id#85], [company_id#180], LeftOuter, None
                      TungstenSort [id#85 ASC], false, 0
                       TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#85)
                        TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,(_we0#194 * 100.0) AS growth_rate_percentile#193]
                         Window [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191], [HiveWindowFunction#org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFPercentRank(growth_rate#191) WindowSpecDefinition ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING AS _we0#194], [ref_company_size_id#96], [growth_rate#191 ASC]
                          TungstenSort [ref_company_size_id#96 ASC,growth_rate#191 ASC], false, 0
                           TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(ref_company_size_id#96)
                            TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,(100.0 * cast(pythonUDF#192 as double)) AS growth_rate#191]
                             !BatchPythonEvaluation PythonUDF#divide(count#190L,emp_count#94L), [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,count#190L,pythonUDF#192]
                              ConvertToSafe
                               TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,count#190L]
                                SortMergeOuterJoin [id#85], [company_id#180], LeftOuter, None
                                 TungstenSort [id#85 ASC], false, 0
                                  TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#85)
                                   TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,(_we0#176 * 100.0) AS emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96]
                                    Window [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,ref_company_size_id#96], [HiveWindowFunction#org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFPercentRank(emp_count#94L) WindowSpecDefinition ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING AS _we0#176], [ref_company_size_id#96], [emp_count#94L ASC]
                                     TungstenSort [ref_company_size_id#96 ASC,emp_count#94L ASC], false, 0
```

And here's another example of a different stack trace (same program, same number of workers):

```
  /home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.093920/pymysql/cursors.py:146: Warning: Can't create database 'v2'; database exists
    result = self._query(query)
  /home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.093920/pymysql/cursors.py:146: Warning: Table 'oplog' already exists
    result = self._query(query)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.093920/spark_normalize_data.py", line 102, in <module>
      run_spark(args)
    File "/home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.093920/spark_normalize_data.py", line 62, in run_spark
      company_aliases_broadcast, experiences, args)
    File "/home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.093920/companies.py", line 50, in get_companies
      out(sc, args, 'companies', sql_create_table, companies)
    File "/home/hadoop/rantav.spark_normalize_data.py.093920/output.py", line 35, in out
      if data.count() > 0:
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 268, in count
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 36, in deco
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o469.count.
  : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
  TungstenAggregate(key=[], functions=[(count(1),mode=Final,isDistinct=false)], output=[count#216L])
   TungstenExchange SinglePartition
    TungstenAggregate(key=[], functions=[(count(1),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[currentCount#219L])
     TungstenProject
      Window [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,churn_rate#200,churn_rate_percentile#202,retention_rate_2y#210], [HiveWindowFunction#org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFPercentRank(retention_rate_2y#210) WindowSpecDefinition ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING AS _we0#213], [ref_company_size_id#96], [retention_rate_2y#210 ASC]
       TungstenSort [ref_company_size_id#96 ASC,retention_rate_2y#210 ASC], false, 0
        TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(ref_company_size_id#96)
         TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,churn_rate#200,churn_rate_percentile#202,retention_rate_2y#210]
          SortMergeOuterJoin [id#85], [company_id#180], LeftOuter, None
           TungstenSort [id#85 ASC], false, 0
            TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#85)
             TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,churn_rate#200,(_we0#203 * 100.0) AS churn_rate_percentile#202]
              Window [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,churn_rate#200], [HiveWindowFunction#org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFPercentRank(churn_rate#200) WindowSpecDefinition ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING AS _we0#203], [ref_company_size_id#96], [churn_rate#200 ASC]
               TungstenSort [ref_company_size_id#96 ASC,churn_rate#200 ASC], false, 0
                TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(ref_company_size_id#96)
                 TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,(100.0 * cast(pythonUDF#201 as double)) AS churn_rate#200]
                  !BatchPythonEvaluation PythonUDF#divide(count#199L,emp_count#94L), [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,count#199L,pythonUDF#201]
                   ConvertToSafe
                    TungstenProject [id#85,href#86,name#87,emp_count#94L,emp_count_percentile#175,ref_company_size_id#96,growth_rate#191,growth_rate_percentile#193,avg_tenure#196,avg_tenure_percentile#197,count#199L]
                     SortMergeOuterJoin [id#85], [company_id#180], LeftOuter, None
                      TungstenSort [id#85 ASC], false, 0
                       TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#85)
```

Comment: It looks you apply complex transformations with long lineages and some Python UDFs on the way. This is generally speaking asking for troubles. Some transformations look suspicious (like multiple shuffles over the same column).

Comment: So, are there best practices to re-do such code? I must use many transformations, and UDFs are essential. I am having similar log errors running my code on 2.5M data set (works on 1M data set). Terminates with `Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used.`